# how to set my own images to the slider?

Tags: views, javascript

I have been trying to make a slide show on the front page but I am facing an issue on how to upload images of my choice in the slide show. I.e. the images that I have in my computers folder.

I have created a view and placed an image field in it, everything is set. I have also added the block to the main page content. All I can see on the front page is the slider title obviously since i have not been able to add any images.
Can any body tell me how to set my own images to the slider?
I don't want to use fixer slider.

I have used views slide show and some other js files for cycle.